# Arabic characters showing as garbage in .Net when getting data from Sybase

Tags: .net, winforms, encoding, odbc, sap-ase

I am trying to display Arabic characters from Sybase database using .Net Windows Forms application but they appear as garbage. I am using ODBC.

If I use ADO.Net then characters are displayed fine so the problem is only in ODBC (and OlEDB which I have also tried)

I tried to user `CharSet=UTF8` in ODBC connection string but I started getting error `Invalid character conversion`. Here's my connecting string:

```
<add name="SybaseString" connectionString="DSN=myDatabase;UID=sa;PWD=sa123;CharSet=utf8" />
```

While displaying I am not doing anything fancy, just directly displaying data like this `reader["ArabicName"].ToString()`

There is no issue with how data is stored in database because when using ADO.Net it works fine. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Ok using character set `cp1256` in connection string fixed the issue. So final connection string would look like this:

```
<add name="SybaseString" connectionString="DSN=myDatabase;UID=sa;PWD=sa123;CharSet=cp1256" />
```

How I found out? First I ran this command sp_helpsort to find out character set used by the database. There I saw that the char set is `cp1256` so I used the same and now it is working fine.